# Field collection new own field

Tags: entities

I try to insert new field (title) into field_collection_field_widget_form like this:

```
 $element['title_collection'] = array(
                    '#delta' => $delta,
                    '#name' => 'title',
                    '#type' => 'textfield',
                    '#title' => t('Collection name'),
                    '#default_value' => 1234
                );
```

I have problem to set default_value for my field. I use default module field collection.

I tried use `$field_collection_item->title` (my variable into db)
But problem is that I can't change value in form. 
When i change 333 => 222 form sent 222. What I do wrong?